# Unnecessary folders under /media starting with ass

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

kernel 5.15.0-82 generic

I haven't connected any external drive to my laptop since Sept 8.
And on Sept 9, I saw 1000s of such ass* folders, which I deleted.
These seems to be created by a process running as root. And if I remove them, it doesn't affect the system.

Anyone has any idea why and who creates these? And how I can stop it?

I'm trying to use a terminal file manager that relies on pmount, and it mounts usb under /media, hence these are a problem for me now, while browsing.

Thanks.

[image: image_link_for_folders_under_media]

Comment: See if you can identify what writes those files with something like: sdo lsof |grep root